# Concourse templating: How to escape double curly-braces (parameters), to use as literals?

Tags: concourse

How do we escape double curly braces and use them as literals instead of fly interpreting them as parameters?

I wan to be able to do something like:

```
jobs:
- task: greet-him
  params:
    STRING: 'Hello {{firstname}} {{lastname}}!'
```

With the `STRING` param as a literal string.

Comment: Would it make sense to have a variable such as `my-var: Hello {{firstname}} {{lastname}}!` and then have `STRING: {{my-var}}`. Without more context it would be difficult to say.

Comment: Yes it makes sense. But I'm asking without using params/variables.

Comment: I am not sure how it should be the escape but I had a look on some Concourse code and it seems to be `\{` and `\}`. Can you try with that?